# Como saber se a data escolhida é menor que a data atual?

Tags: javascript, data, comparação

Preciso emitir um alert caso a data de escolhida seja menor que a data atual.
Fiz assim:

```js
var strData = "15/08/2017";
var partesData = strData.split("/");
var data = new Date(partesData[2], partesData[1] - 1, partesData[0]).toDateString();
if(data < new Date().toDateString())
{
   alert("Menor");
   }
```

Coloquei dia 15 e retornou Menor.

> Está certo

Coloquei dia 16 não retornou nada.

> Está certo

**Coloquei dia 17 e retornou Menor**

> Está errado

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando

Comment: Tentou tirar o `toDateString` e só comparar puramente a data?

Comment: Se eu tirar ele acusa que conta os milesegundos

Comment: ajustei a minha resposta para remover o tempo e comparar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remova o `toDateString` na comparação, senão estará comparando valor de `Strings`:

```js
comparar("17/08/2017");
comparar("16/08/2017");
comparar("15/08/2017");

function comparar(strData) {
  var partesData = strData.split("/");
  var data = new Date(partesData[2], partesData[1] - 1, partesData[0]);
  var hoje = new Date();

  hoje = new Date(hoje.getFullYear(), hoje.getUTCMonth(), hoje.getUTCDate());

  if (data < hoje) {
    console.log(strData, "Menor");
  }
}
```

Realizei a conversão removendo as opções de hora criando uma nova data.

Comment: Eu já estava testando e vi que estava contando a hora.

Comment: @durtto alterei pra remover a hora!

Comment: @Sorack, adicionando a hora como ficaria

Comment: @RenanRodrigues dá uma olhada nas edições. A primeira versão considerava a hora.

Answer (score 4):

Não compares datas em formato *string* usando o `toDateString`. Podes comparar diretamente o objeto data:

```js
function comparar(string) {
  var d = string.split("/");
  var data = new Date(d[2], d[1] - 1, d[0]);
  var agora = new Date();
  return data > agora ? 'maior' : 'menor';
}

console.log(["10/08/2017", "15/12/2317"].map(comparar));
```

Answer (score 0):

Forma mais simples

```js
var strDate = "15/08/2017".split('/').reverse();
//Saida -> ["2017", "08", "15"]

//Data em milisegundos 
var currentDate = new Date(strDate).valueOf();
//Data atual em milisegundos 
var dateNow = new Date().valueOf();

if(currentDate < dateNow)
{
   alert("Menor");
}
```